# When can I re-use memory referenced by a netbuf in lwip?

Tags: lwip

I am sending UDP packets from an embedded system using lwip, using the netconn API. I create a netbuf like this:

```
    struct netbuf* buf = netbuf_new();
    netbuf_ref(buf, &signal_packet, sizeof(signal_packet_t));
```

and then I send the UDP packet like this:

```
    err_t err = netconn_send(conn, buf);
```

At what point now can I re-use the memory pointed to by &signal_packet? Does the netconn API make a copy before returning, or does it continue to reference this memory from other threads?